# Is it possible to include formatting (i.e. HTML) in the description of a Maven POM?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'd like to have useful urls and a bit of tidiness in the description and other text fields of my Maven generated site.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which fields exactly? Can you give examples?

Comment: <project>...<description> Blah blah blah [www.coolsite.example this is a cool site] yada yada yada</description>...</project>

Comment: within description you can use CDATA as in XML ....

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking about `maven-site-plugin`, you can customize your site by modifying the [default template](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/doxia/doxia-sitetools/trunk/doxia-site-renderer/src/main/resources/org/apache/maven/doxia/siterenderer/resources/default-site.vm), which uses `Velocity` as template engine, by specifying something like this:

```
    <configuration>
      <templateFile>${basedir}/maven-site.vm</templateFile>
    </configuration>
```

Reference documentation [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/templatefile.html).

Also, keep in mind from their documentation, this method has downsides.

> Note: If you use this method then skins and the default templates, CSS
>   and images are disabled. It is therefor highly recommended that you
>   package this as a [skin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creatingskins.html) instead.

EDIT:
You can add `CDATA` tag to include more sofisticated description like so:

```
<description>
    <![CDATA[
        <p>This is a description including html tags and whatnot</p>
    ]]>
</description>
```

Comment: Templates and skins will effect the entire site.  Is there a gentler tool for adding HTML to, for example, project.description?

Comment: @GregoryGraham check my edit. Is this something you looking for?